# software integration visualization & change simulation

Tags: architecture, integration, visualization

Background to the problem : I am working for a very complex automotive data management company. We have different applications with different data bases but all databases are interconnected.

A change implementation in a data model in one application may influence a change consideration in some other application. This cannot be foreseen since the complexity is high. To make a decision, we are forced to review many documents and had to go through many stakeholder reviews.

Do we have any open-source tools or commercial tools to represent complete architecture components and their integration in a enterprise by providing features like integration clear visualization with top down navigator and  change request simulator(I have no clue how to represent this.) which helps identifying the stakeholders and their component influence by any change initiation with in the integration architecture.

Sorry for theory question here but if you have answers i would be very much happy to look my future those recommendations.

Comment: Do you mean pull requests by change requests here? PRs is very good way to make changes atomic enough for review, and for that there is really a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to write my experience where there are 10,000+ interfaces or data exchanges between applications pictorially represented in a web based software.

It is Essential Projects, it is an enterprise architecture platform which has EA Met Models about applications information dependencies, it provides out of the box view to show the integration between applications, which can be used for impact analysis and/or data sensitive assessments.
[Applications Integrations Information Dependency View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb26o.png)

You can visit the view [here](https://essentialviewer.com/demo/report?XML=reportXML.xml&PMA=store_55_Class1161&cl=en-gb&XSL=application/core_al_app_provider_info_deps_model.xsl).

Hope this solves your need.